# dump oracle table (non-partitioned VS partitioned) in flat file performance question

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm requesting your feedback on a test I was asked to setup in java: extract  data from an Oracle table (no WHERE CLAUSE) and store it in a flat file.
Some may say Oracle provides tools to do so and probably better than me but I was asked to wrote my own tool.

I have 2 source table identical except that one is partitioned so my assumption was "if several threads can query each partition and wrote the content in its own file then I expect the extraction of a partitioned table to be faster than a regular table" but my test showed the opposite so I'm bit puzzled and I'd like to have your feedback.

Tables definition (250M rows each)

- tab_non_partitioned (row_num number, row_label char(50));
- tab_partitioned (row_num number,row_label char(50))
  PARTITION BY RANGE(row_num)

  PARTITION part_01 VALUES LESS THAN (50000001) TABLESPACE sst_01,

  PARTITION part_02 VALUES LESS THAN (100000001) TABLESPACE sst_02,

  PARTITION part_03 VALUES LESS THAN (150000001) TABLESPACE sst_03,

  PARTITION part_04 VALUES LESS THAN (200000001) TABLESPACE sst_04,

  PARTITION part_05 VALUES LESS THAN (250000001) TABLESPACE sst_05);

My tool has the following design:

- class OracleWorker: this class executes the select statement and write the content in a file
- class OracleExporter: this class checks if the table is partitioned then exec OracleWorker threads to do the extract

  ```
  -if table is not partitioned then 1 OracleWorker thread is executed to extract the whole content
  -if table is partitioned then each partition is queried by an individual thread. So in my example 5 threads will be executed and dump content in 5 different files
  ```
- classDbExporter: the main class

Below are the classes details (sorry but I'm beginning with java coding so some piece of it might be ugly and I apologize in advance)

**OracleWorker.java:**

```
package DbExporter;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;


public class OracleWorker  implements Callable<Void> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OracleExporter.class.getName());

    private Connection conn;
    private String sqlStmt;
    private int fetchSize;
    private Writer outW;

    OracleWorker(Connection conn, String sql, int size, Path out) throws IOException {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.sqlStmt = sql;
        this.fetchSize = size;
        this.outW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out.toString()), 32768);
        logger.debug("sql to exec: " + sql);
        logger.debug("output: " + out);
    }
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        ResultSetMetaData metaData;
        Instant start, startResult;
        int numOfCols;
        List<Long> dbgRowToString = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> dbgWrite = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder currentRow;

        try{
            stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
            stmt.setFetchSize(this.fetchSize);
            start = Instant.now();
            rset = stmt.executeQuery(this.sqlStmt);
            logger.debug(String.format("sql exec: %s ms", Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis()));

            metaData = rset.getMetaData();
            numOfCols = metaData.getColumnCount();

            startResult = Instant.now();
            while (rset.next()) {
                currentRow = new StringBuilder();
                start = Instant.now();
                for (int i =1; i<numOfCols; i++) currentRow.append(rset.getString(i)).append("|");
                currentRow.append(rset.getString(numOfCols));
                dbgRowToString.add(Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis());

                start = Instant.now();
                this.outW.write(currentRow + System.lineSeparator());
                dbgWrite.add(Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis());
            }

            logger.debug(String.format("fetch result: %s ms", Duration.between(startResult, Instant.now()).toMillis()));
            logger.debug(String.format("avg row to string: %,.4f", dbgRowToString.stream().mapToLong(a -> a).summaryStatistics().getAverage()));
            logger.debug(String.format("avg write to file: %,.4f", dbgWrite.stream().mapToLong(a -> a).summaryStatistics().getAverage()));
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            logger.error("error executing statement");
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if(rset != null) rset.close();
            if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
            this.outW.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**OracleExporter.java:**

```
package DbExporter;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class OracleExporter {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OracleExporter.class.getName());

    private Properties props;
    private Connection conn;

    OracleExporter(Properties prop) throws SQLException {
        this.props = prop;
        try{
            OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
            String url = String.format("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//%s:%s/%s", prop.getProperty("db.hostname"), prop.getProperty("db.port"), prop.getProperty("db.name"));
            ods.setURL(url);
            ods.setUser(prop.getProperty("db.user"));
            ods.setPassword(prop.getProperty("db.password"));
            this.conn = ods.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("error instantiating a connection");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    void execStmt() throws Exception {
        Instant start;
        List<String> sqlPartition = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Path> outPartition = new ArrayList<>();
        String unitPartition;
        String tabName = this.props.getProperty("sql.table").toUpperCase();
        Path outF = Paths.get(this.props.getProperty("output.dir"), tabName + ".csv");

        // add oracle hint /*+ PARALLEL */ in the sql statement
        String sqlNoPartition = String.format(
                "SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ %s FROM %s",
                this.props.getProperty("sql.cols").toUpperCase(), tabName);

        // check if table is partitioned
        Statement stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
        String sqlCheckPartition = String.format(
                "SELECT PARTITION_NAME FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '%s'", tabName);
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlCheckPartition);
        while (rset.next()){
            unitPartition = rset.getString("PARTITION_NAME");
            sqlPartition.add(sqlNoPartition + String.format(" PARTITION(%s)", unitPartition));
            outPartition.add(Paths.get(this.props.getProperty("output.dir"), tabName + "_" + unitPartition + ".csv"));
        }
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<OracleWorker> callableTasks = new ArrayList<OracleWorker>();

        if (sqlPartition.isEmpty()) {
            callableTasks.add(
                    new OracleWorker(
                            this.conn,
                            sqlNoPartition,
                            Integer.parseInt(this.props.getProperty("sql.fetch")),
                            outF)
            );
        }
        else{

            for (int i =0; i < sqlPartition.size();i++){
                callableTasks.add(
                        new OracleWorker(
                                this.conn,
                                sqlPartition.get(i),
                                Integer.parseInt(this.props.getProperty("sql.fetch")),
                                outPartition.get(i)
                        )
                );
            }
        }

        start = Instant.now();
        logger.info("TEST STARTING...please wait");
        for (Future<Void> f : executorService.invokeAll(callableTasks)) f.get();
        logger.info(String.format("TEST ELAPSED: %s ms", Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis()));

       executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!executorService.awaitTermination(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) executorService.shutdownNow();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    protected  void finalize(){
        try{
            if(this.conn != null) this.conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**DbExporter.java:**

```
package DbExporter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class DbExporter {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DbExporter.class.getName());

    private static void errorAndExit(String msg){
        logger.error(msg);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        String configFile = System.getProperty("configFile", "");
        OracleExporter cli;

        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(configFile));
            properties.load(fis);
            fis.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            errorAndExit("problem with file " + configFile);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try{
            cli = new OracleExporter(properties);
            cli.execStmt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally my config file:**

```
db.vendor=ORACLE
db.hostname=my_server
db.port=1521
db.name=MY_ORACLE_INSTANCE
db.schema=MY_ORACLE_SCHEMA
db.user=SST
db.password=xxx
sql.fetch=300
sql.table=tab_partitioned
sql.cols=row_num, row_label
output.dir=/storage_location/
```

Below are the result of my test

```
# execution on partitioned table
2022-04-28 15:05:04,442[main][OracleExporter][execStmt]-INFO- TEST STARTING...please wait
2022-04-28 15:16:08,430[main][OracleExporter][execStmt]-INFO- TEST ELAPSED: 663987 ms
# execution on non_partitioned table
bash$ /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131-x64/bin/java -Dlogfilename=dbg.log -DconfigFile=sample_config.properties -jar db_exporter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
2022-04-28 15:23:13,530[main][OracleExporter][execStmt]-INFO- TEST STARTING...please wait
2022-04-28 15:32:47,439[main][OracleExporter][execStmt]-INFO- TEST ELAPSED: 573909 ms
```

Please note that playing with the resultSet fetch size improved the timing but the non_partitioned table extraction is still faster than the partitioned table

I'd be happy to have your thoughts about my test and I thank you in advance

Comment: Have you done anything to profile the code both to see where the database is waiting and where the Java application is waiting?  One possibility is that since you're asking for Oracle to run each query in parallel that you're got too many parallel workers running on the server when you have N Java threads each spawning M parallel workers in the database (this will depend on what M is in this case as well as what as database hardware). But it could be something else-- maybe the network is the bottleneck and you happened to run the first test when there was activity.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your feedback. I haven't done any profiling, let me check how to do that  through my IDE. But before that I checked the content of my dbg.log. My code compute the time taken to transform a row to a string then the time taken to write to file (OracleWorker.java). I noticed that in the case of a non-partitioned table I have the following info "DEBUG- avg row to string: 0.0006", while for the partitioned table I have "DEBUG- avg row to string: 0.0043". Maybe something I should look at

Comment: Interestingly, I exec my program while querying my partitioned table and plug jvisualvm on it. Looking at the monitor tab, I could see my some of my threads (5 threads because 5 partitions) were blocked.

A thread dump actually shows 4 of them were waiting to lock the same address that was blocked but the 5th threads.

Therefore instead of having a Connections shared between threads, I change my code to have a dedicated Conn per thread and this time the elapsed wen down to 102517 ms. So it looks like my design was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code by setting a dedicated connection per thread instead of a shared connection